# Lambda expression throws exception

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, lambda, vaadin

I just started a new vaadin project with maven (com.vaadin:vaadin-archetype-application@7.2.6).

In the default `MyVaadinUI.java` i have replaced the `Butten.ClickListener()` with a lambda expression, after that i get a exception while running `package jetty:run`

Before:

```
Button button = new Button("Click Me");
  button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
      layout.addComponent(new Label("Thank you for clicking"));
    }
});
layout.addComponent(button);
```

After:

```
Button button = new Button("Click Me");
button.addClickListener(event -> layout.addComponent(new Label("Thank you for clicking")));
layout.addComponent(button);
```

Exception:

```
2014-08-26 13:23:30.069:WARN:oeja.AnnotationParser:EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1612
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:744)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.MavenAnnotationConfiguration.doParse(MavenAnnotationConfiguration.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.MavenAnnotationConfiguration.parseWebInfClasses(MavenAnnotationConfiguration.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1237)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:520)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:365)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:523)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I`m using IntelliJ13.1 with JDK8 on OSX

Comment: I'd say that your version of [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) does not support Java 8. Jetty is using ASM to scan binary classes for annotations.

Comment: thx, updating `jetty-maven-plugin` solved it for me.

Comment: thanks, I had the same issue and using jetty-maven-plugin 9.2.2.v20140723 instead of 9.0.6.v20130930 fix the issue.

Comment: Hi, what version of jetty are you using? I'm using 8.1.16.v20140903 and I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: @CodeJunkie I am experiencing the same issue with `Jetty 8.1.2.v20120308`, as @Schrodinger's'Cat said, you can upgrade to 9.2.2 and it should fix.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue when I deployed the app in jetty `8.12.x`.
I resolved the issue by upgrading to jetty `9.2.x`. (Yes, lambdas are used in app)

Answer (score 3):

I've read a lot of pages about this issue because I encountered it too.

For me the solution was simple but hard to be found.
I use jetty-8.1.10 with asm-3.3.1 and primefaces-5.1.

The problem appears when you have lambda expressions in any of the annotated classes, or in any class referenced by the annotated ones.

Simply changing the code from Java 8 compliance in Java 7 compliance (lambda expressions in normal Java 7 code), the warns had gone away.
This was only possible debugging the `org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader`.

Cheers.